# GroupBy with or without sum

Tags: c#

I currently have the following groupby which gets the sum of officials travel expenses

```
var travelExpenesPerOfficial = model.GroupBy(x=> new {x.OfficialsName, x.EventLocationAdddress,x.FixtureDate,x.OfficialTravelExpenses})
                .Select(y=> new FixturesViewModel
            {
                FixtureDate             = y.Key.FixtureDate,
                OfficialsName           = y.Key.OfficialsName,
                EventLocationAdddress   = y.Key.EventLocationAdddress,
                OfficialTravelExpenses  = y.Sum(ote=>ote.OfficialTravelExpenses)
                }).ToList();
```

The problem is if the official is at the same EventLocationAdddress on the same FixtureDate more than once, I only want to get the 1st travel expense not the sum.

I'm struggling on working this out, so any help would be appreciated.

------------------Extra Info---------------------

```
Fixture Date | OfficialsName | EventLocationAdddress | OfficialTravelExpenses

01/03/2020,    Official One,        Location One,              0.50

01/03/2020,    Official One,        Location One,              0.50

01/03/2020,    Official Two,        Location One,              1.50

02/03/2020,    Official One,        Location Two,              1.50

02/03/2020,    Official Two,        Location Two,              1.50
```

For Official One, I'm looking for the OfficialTravelExpenses to be 2.0 - Location One(First) + Location Two

For Official Two, I'm looking for the OfficialTravelExpenses to be 3.0

The official could referee more than 1 match at the same location on the same day, but I only need 1 travel expense

Comment: Did you try y.Select(ote=>ote.OfficialTravelExpenses).First()?

Comment: Hi @Posix, yes tried that and it works if the official is at the same address more than once on the same day, but if they are at multiple EventLocationAdddress on different FixtureDate then I want to get the sum of their expenses if that makes sense

Comment: Provide examples (input and expected output)

Comment: Hi @Posix, please see added extra info

Comment: First two rows are duplicates? Can you get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to remove the "EventLocationAdddress" parameter from the group. You should try as follows.

```
    void Main(){
        var fixture = new List<model>(){
                      new model{FixtureDate=new DateTime(01/03/2020), OfficialsName=  "Official One",EventLocationAdddress="Location One", OfficialTravelExpenses=0.50},
                      new model{FixtureDate=new DateTime(01/03/2020), OfficialsName=  "Official One",EventLocationAdddress="Location One", OfficialTravelExpenses=0.50}   ,
                      new model{FixtureDate=new DateTime(01/03/2020), OfficialsName=  "Official Two",EventLocationAdddress="Location One", OfficialTravelExpenses=1.50},
                      new model{FixtureDate=new DateTime(02/03/2020), OfficialsName=  "Official One",EventLocationAdddress="Location Two", OfficialTravelExpenses=1.50},
                      new model{FixtureDate=new DateTime(02/03/2020), OfficialsName=  "Official Two",EventLocationAdddress="Location Two", OfficialTravelExpenses=1.50}
                      };


        var travelExpenesPerOfficial = fixture.Select(f => new { f.FixtureDate, f.OfficialsName, f.EventLocationAdddress, f.OfficialTravelExpenses })
                         .Distinct()
                         .GroupBy(x => new { x.OfficialsName,x.EventLocationAdddress, x.FixtureDate, x.OfficialTravelExpenses })
                         .Select(y => new model(){      
                               FixtureDate = y.Key.FixtureDate,
                               OfficialsName = y.Key.OfficialsName,                                  
                               EventLocationAdddress=y.Key.EventLocationAdddress,
                               OfficialTravelExpenses = y.Sum(ote => ote.OfficialTravelExpenses)
                                }).ToList().Dump();
                               }
                            }   

class model{
  public DateTime FixtureDate { get; set; }
  public string OfficialsName { get; set; }
  public string EventLocationAdddress { get; set; }
  public double OfficialTravelExpenses { get; set; }              
}
```

Comment: Hi @KdrGny that does not work, official one for 01/03/2020 should only return .50 not 1, as I only need 1 travel expense per location per date

Comment: Hello @George Phillipson, I did it in your code. I added the "different" code. In this way, you get the result you want.